# How to move terabytes of data from Blob Storage to Synapse?

Tags: azure-synapse, azure-synapse-analytics, azure-synapse-pipeline

I have thousands of compressed CSV files to be copied to a SQL dedicated pool in Synapse. I have tried the following and all of them either failed or just took too long (days) to complete and I'm wondering if I am doing the right thing here.

1. Polybase with staging. I had to pick staging since the requirement is to lose the escape character in the dataset which if I do would screw up the columns
2. Bulk Insert. This is the most promising although there are a few failures and it's taking more than 4 days (and counting) and it's still 70% in progress.
3. I tried with ADX LightIngest as well as I thought maybe I can connect ADX with Synapse. Quite performant as i moved 40 files worth of data within 1 hour, then the whole thing timed out

So, how do I copy these terabytes worth of data to Synapse as fast as I can? Cost is the least concern. I was thinking of writing my own script to copy the data with Python or Go...

Comment: Check this
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-synapse-analytics-blog/writing-data-using-azure-synapse-dedicated-sql-pool-connector/ba-p/3535930